# Как сделать чтобы столбцы в заголовке и столбцы в содержимом таблицы совпадали?

Tags: html5, table

Есть пример таблицы на codepen https://codepen.io/geeny273/pen/vMvmLm?editors=1000. В столбцы в заголовке и в основной части таблицы не совпадают из-за скрола. Как сделать так, чтобы они совпадали?

```
<html>
  <div>
    <div>
      <table border="" style="width: 100%">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th style="width: 10%"> Name
            <th style="width: 20%"> Surname
            <th style="width: 20%"> Age
          <tr>
        </thead>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div style="height: 100px; overflow: auto;">
      <table border="" style="width: 100%">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td style="width: 10%">name1
            <td style="width: 20%">sname1
            <td style="width: 20%">age1
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>name2
            <td>sname2
            <td>age2
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>name3
            <td>sname3
            <td>age3
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>name4
            <td>sname5
            <td>age5
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>name5
            <td>sname6
            <td>age6
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>name7
            <td>sname7
            <td>age7
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>name8
            <td>sname8
            <td>age8
          </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
        table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
        }
        thead {
            background-color: #333;
            color: #fff;
        }
        thead,tbody {
            display: block;
        }
        th,td {
            padding: 8px 10px;
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            width: 117px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        tbody {
            height: 160px;
            overflow-y: scroll
        }
```

```html
    <table class="example-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th> Header 1 </th>
                <th> Header 2 </th>
                <th> Header 3 </th>
                <th> Header 4 </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td> Row 1- Col 1 </td>
                <td> Row 1- Col 2 </td>
                <td> Row 1- Col 3 </td>
                <td> Row 1- Col 4 </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> Row 2- Col 1 </td>
                <td> Row 2- Col 2 </td>
                <td> Row 2- Col 3 </td>
                <td> Row 2- Col 4 </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> Row 3- Col 1 </td>
                <td> Row 3- Col 2 </td>
                <td> Row 3- Col 3 </td>
                <td> Row 3- Col 4 </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> Row 4- Col 1 </td>
                <td> Row 4- Col 2 </td>
                <td> Row 4- Col 3 </td>
                <td> Row 4- Col 4 </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> Row 5- Col 1 </td>
                <td> Row 5- Col 2 </td>
                <td> Row 5- Col 3 </td>
                <td> Row 5- Col 4 </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> Row 6- Col 1 </td>
                <td> Row 6- Col 2 </td>
                <td> Row 6- Col 3 </td>
                <td> Row 6- Col 4 </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> Row 7- Col 1 </td>
                <td> Row 7- Col 2 </td>
                <td> Row 7- Col 3 </td>
                <td> Row 7- Col 4 </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> Row 8- Col 1 </td>
                <td> Row 8- Col 2 </td>
                <td> Row 8- Col 3 </td>
                <td> Row 8- Col 4 </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> Row 9- Col 1 </td>
                <td> Row 9- Col 2 </td>
                <td> Row 9- Col 3 </td>
                <td> Row 9- Col 4 </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> Row 10- Col 1 </td>
                <td> Row 10- Col 2 </td>
                <td> Row 10- Col 3 </td>
                <td> Row 10- Col 4 </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> Row 11- Col 1 </td>
                <td> Row 11- Col 2 </td>
                <td> Row 11- Col 3 </td>
                <td> Row 11- Col 4 </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> Row 12- Col 1 </td>
                <td> Row 12- Col 2 </td>
                <td> Row 12- Col 3 </td>
                <td> Row 12- Col 4 </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> Row 13- Col 1 </td>
                <td> Row 13- Col 2 </td>
                <td> Row 13- Col 3 </td>
                <td> Row 13- Col 4 </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> Row 14- Col 1 </td>
                <td> Row 14- Col 2 </td>
                <td> Row 14- Col 3 </td>
                <td> Row 14- Col 4 </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> Row 15- Col 1 </td>
                <td> Row 15- Col 2 </td>
                <td> Row 15- Col 3 </td>
                <td> Row 15- Col 4 </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> Row 16- Col 1 </td>
                <td> Row 16- Col 2 </td>
                <td> Row 16- Col 3 </td>
                <td> Row 16- Col 4 </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Возможно ли для этого примера добавить скролл для table body?

Comment: @Fedchenko Отредактировал код

Comment: Спасибо, как один из вариантов решения возможен. Является ли это хорошей практикой заменять свойства tbody и thead на display block?

Comment: @Fedchenko,  я ничего в этом плохого не вижу

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
  <div>
    <div>
    </div>
    <div style="height: 100px; overflow: auto;">
      <table border="" style="width: 100%">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th style="width: 10%"> Name
            <th style="width: 20%"> Surname
            <th style="width: 20%"> Age
          <tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td style="width: 10%">name1
            <td style="width: 20%">sname1
            <td style="width: 20%">age1
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>name2
            <td>sname2
            <td>age2
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>name3
            <td>sname3
            <td>age3
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>name4
            <td>sname5
            <td>age5
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>name5
            <td>sname6
            <td>age6
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>name7
            <td>sname7
            <td>age7
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>name8
            <td>sname8
            <td>age8
          </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</html>
```

Зачем thead вынесли в отдельный блок?

Comment: Для того, чтобы зафиксировать высоту основного содержимого и добавить для него скролл. Это единственно решение, которое я пока нашла. Потому что css свойство display: table-row-group которое применяется к tbody - не реагирует на css свойства width, height